# Is there a way to obfuscate an address in a source file?

Tags: contract-development, security, build-from-source

Is there a way to obfuscate an address in a source file of a smart contract? And if so, how?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Some honey pot contracts use `keccak256(address)` as a way to hide their addresses. Obviously it only works until they use them for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can encrypt it with whatever encryption you want, and store it as a string (or bytes). That way the address will not be visible in plaintext in the contract.

The obvious downside is, since the contact can't decrypt the data, the contract has no idea what the underlying address is and it can't utilize that address in any way. Furthermore, if the contract was able to decrypt the string back into an address, everyone else could do it as well. So that would be quite pointless.

In short, you can't have secrets in the blockchain.

Comment: My question isn't about secrets or encryption, but about obfuscation

Comment: Well you can for example concatenate a random string to it, if you want. Or flip it back-to-front. Or anything you want. But the same issues remain: the address itself can't be utilized in the contract as an address.

Comment: It could be utilized in a contract, even when obfuscated. You haven't understood my question.